# IllegalStateException: Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided

Tags: java, multipartfile

Есть у меня контроллерный метод:

```
@PutMapping(value = "/mail",
            consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Report> mail(@RequestPart("data") MailMessageDto dto,
                                       @RequestPart(value = "attachments", required = false) List<MultipartFile> attachments) {
```

В него должны приходить два мультипарта - JSON (файлом, здесь он "data") и несколько файлов (здесь они "attachments").

Я добавил резолвер:

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig {

    @Bean
    public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(50000000);
        multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSizePerFile(5000000);
        return multipartResolver;
    }
}
```

Зависимости:

```
compile group: 'commons-fileupload', name: 'commons-fileupload', version: '1.3.3'
compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'
```

Вроде, должно работать, но нет:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to process parts as no
>   multi-part configuration has been provided
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2719)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParts(Request.java:2685)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParts(RequestFacade.java:1083)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getParts(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:347)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getParts(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:347)
>     org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.parseRequest(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:91)
>     org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:84)
>     org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:69)
>     org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartResolutionDelegate.asMultipartHttpServletRequest(MultipartResolutionDelegate.java:59)
>     org.springframework.web.multipart.support.RequestPartServletServerHttpRequest.(RequestPartServletServerHttpRequest.java:65)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestPartMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(RequestPartMethodArgumentResolver.java:131)
>     org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:124)
>     org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:161)
>     org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:131)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:871)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:892)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:651)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:176)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)

Подскажите, что не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что `MultipartFile` можно отправить только через `POST`, а написано было `PUT`.